Flicker Phenomenon When Switching NSIS Custom Pages
I created several Custom pages as below. For each page custom function, do 'nsdialog::Create~nsdialog::show'.
And call the LoadBannerImage function every few pages
Images are placed in fixed positions on each page.
I did lockWindow on~off, but every time I did next or prev button on the page The banner image is flickering and redrawing (including other controllers also blinking)
It is more visible in low-spec virtual machine environments.
How can I solve this phenomenon more naturally?
Page custom DisplayWelcomePage
Page custom DisplayInstallationDirPage LeaveInstDirPage
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW InstallPage
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
Page custom DisplayInstallationFinishPage

;WelcomePage.nsi file

Function DisplayWelcomePage
nsDialogs::Create 1044
Pop $r0
SetCtlColors $r0 0 0xF5F5F5
Push $r0

Call LoadBannerImage
nsDialogs::Show
FuncionEnd

; InstallReadyPage.nsi file

Function DisplayInstallationDirPage 
nsDialogs::Create 1044
Pop $r0
SetCtlColors $r0 0 0xF5F5F5
Push $r0
Call LoadBannerImage

nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd



loadBannerImage

Function LoadBannerImage
    ${NSD_CreateBitmap} 0u 0u 100u 434u ""
    Pop $BannerImage
    SetCtlColors $BannerImage 0 0xF5F5F5
    ${NSD_SetBitmap} $BannerImage ${TempBannerFilePath} $8
FunctionEnd


Are you using a custom UI .exe? What is WITHOUTHEADER_INTERFACE defined as? Ideally you should post complete code I can compile...

This is modern.exe that 1044 ID.

A NSIS page is a inner dialog inside the main dialog window and any NSD control you create will live inside this inner dialog. The control will be destroyed before the next page is visible so there is no wonder you get flicker.
NSIS was never designed to have full background images but some people do it anyway (ExperienceUI, UltraModernUI and Graphical Installer).
If you insist on doing it yourself, perhaps start by having a background image in the main dialog window:
InstallDir $ProgramFiles\MyApp
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT myGuiInit
!include MUI2.nsh

!define BMPFILE "bug.bmp"
!define BMPWIDTH 96
!define BMPHEIGHT 96
Var BannerImageControl

Page custom DisplayWelcomePage
Page custom DisplayInstallationDirPage LeaveInstDirPage
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW InstallPage
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
Page custom DisplayInstallationFinishPage
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

!macro ToggleMUIHeader sw
ShowWindow $mui.Header.Text ${sw}
ShowWindow $mui.Header.SubText ${sw}
ShowWindow $mui.Header.Background ${sw}
ShowWindow $mui.Header.Image ${sw}
GetDlgItem $0 $hWndParent 1036
ShowWindow $0 ${sw}
IntOp $0 ${sw} !
ShowWindow $BannerImageControl $0
!macroend

!macro BgPageBegin hWndDlg
!insertmacro ToggleMUIHeader 0
nsDialogs::Create 1044
Pop ${hWndDlg}
SetCtlColors ${hWndDlg} ${MUI_TEXTCOLOR} transparent
!macroend

!macro BgPageShow
nsDialogs::Show
!macroend

Function myGUIInit
InitPluginsDir
File "/oname=$PluginsDir\background.bmp" "${BMPFILE}"
System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i0,t"STATIC",p0,i${__NSD_Bitmap_STYLE},i0,i0,i${BMPWIDTH},i${BMPHEIGHT},p$hWndParent,p0,p0,p0)p.r0'
LoadAndSetImage /STRINGID /RESIZETOFITWIDTH $0 0 0x10 "$PluginsDir\background.bmp"
StrCpy $BannerImageControl $0
!insertmacro ToggleMUIHeader 0
FunctionEnd

Function DisplayWelcomePage
!insertmacro BgPageBegin $r0
${NSD_CreateLabel} 10 10u 90% 12u "Hello and welcome to my installer!"
Pop $0
SetCtlColors $0 ${MUI_TEXTCOLOR} transparent
!insertmacro BgPageShow
FunctionEnd

Function DisplayInstallationDirPage
!insertmacro BgPageBegin $r0
${NSD_CreateLabel} 10 0 90% 12u "A directory perhaps?"
Pop $0
SetCtlColors $0 ${MUI_TEXTCOLOR} transparent
${NSD_CreateText} 8u 13u -16u 12u "$InstDir"
Pop $0
!insertmacro BgPageShow
FunctionEnd

Function LeaveInstDirPage
#?
FunctionEnd

Function InstallPage
!insertmacro ToggleMUIHeader 1 ; Make this page look normal
FunctionEnd

Function DisplayInstallationFinishPage
!insertmacro BgPageBegin $r0
${NSD_CreateLabel} 10 10u 90% 12u "Goodbye"
Pop $0
SetCtlColors $0 ${MUI_TEXTCOLOR} transparent
!insertmacro BgPageShow
FunctionEnd

Section
SectionEnd

If you want custom looking buttons, you have to use one of the NSIS skinning plug-ins, you cannot use SetCtlColors because Windows does not support custom button colors.

Other controllers other than the image also have a flicker phenomenon on custom page (such as text, edit, and so on...)
do i have to take this for granted?

Probably. This design is or 20 years old, it was never meant for controls to last longer than a single page. But you can take a look at the 3 alternatives I listed above, they probably do it better than what I can do in a simple answer here...
